# Параллельность в Clang

Tags: c++, parallel

Поддерживается ли в Clang (точнее в libc++) какая либо параллельность?

В GCC (точнее в libcstd++), до C++17 был Parallel Mode с openMP, а после C++17 в STL появилась поддержка Parallel Standard Algorithms, используящая execution policies и технологию TBB.

Почему же в Clang (libc++) ничего нет? Более того, в последних версиях Clang стало невозможно использовать -stdlib=libcstd++, по крайней мере в macOS. Прикрутить тот же tbb к Clang (libc++) не выйдет. Неужели остаются только POSIX потоки и все? Я ничего не пропустил?

Например, этот код, использующий параллельную версию алгоритма std::sort, скомпилирует в GCC, но не скомпилирует в Clang(libc++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <execution>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::iota (std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
 
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
 
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::sort(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end()); // Execution policy of parallel algorithms

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oneTBB судя по cmake файлам собирается для apple https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/tree/master/cmake/compilers

Comment: А почему сразу POSIX-потоки, если есть `std::thread`? Судя по [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) поддерживается все, кроме этого самого `<execution>` и новомодного `std::jthread` (`std::async` и всякие многопоточные примитивы, типа мьютексов и атомиков).

Comment: *"в последних версиях Clang стало невозможно использовать -stdlib=libcstd++"* Возможно в Apple Clang (их форке кланга), и то в гугле я нашел только объявление поддержки libstdc++ deprecated, а не полное прекращение работы. Сам кланг славится совместимостью со стандартными библиотеками от других компиляторов, и вряд ли они станут от этого отказываться.

Comment: Не путайте параллелизм с конкурентностью.

Comment: Я не очень понял, что имеется ввиду под параллельностью, т.к. в `STD/STL` есть *Concurrency support library*. И почему `Clang` несовместим с `Intel TBB` или `OpenMP`? Что его мешает сбилдить и подключить? И причём тут платформозависимые `POSIX`-потоки, когда, опять же, есть *Concurrency support library*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, вы правы, std::thread обеспечивает переносимость на различных платформах, это вариант.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, "только объявление поддержки libstdc++ deprecated, а не полное прекращение работы" - полностью не поддерживается форком кланга от apple, проверено.

Comment: @megorit, платформозависимые POSIX-потоки были упомянуты только потому, что даже та самая библиотека std::thread, о которой шла речь выше, реализована поверх pthreads в среде, поддерживающей pthreads (например: libstdc++). И большинство интерфейсов для параллельных вычислений - это абстракция над потоками ОС. Речь в данном треде конечно же идет только о параллелизме, а не конкурентности, очевидно, что это разные вещи.

Comment: @megorit, "И почему Clang несовместим с Intel TBB или OpenMP?" - о какой совместимости Вы говорите? Речь шла о том, что стандартные алгоритмы билиотеки libc++ не имеют параллельных версий, которые, в свою очередь, могли бы использовать Intel TBB или OpenMP, или любой другой фреймворк для параллельных вычислений. Кстати говоря, с недавнего времени в libc++ включили поддержку MapReduce алгоритмов (reduce, transform и др.), но при этом нет поддержки execution policy и параллельный режим непонятно как реализован у них (если он есть вообще). Возможно, execution policy скоро также появятся.

Comment: @Давид, хм, а почему для вас так важно что C++ использует под капотом? STD просто должен работать на каждой платформе. Не всё ли равно, что он исплользует? А если не всё равно, так может стоит подключить желаемую библиотеку при билде?

Comment: @Давид, я прекрасно это знаю, и потому не понимаю, зачем вообще ковыряться в кишках. Так то даже `CMake` не подключит `pthreads` без явного указания.

Comment: @megorit, ну вот лично я столкнулся с проблемой того, что код, поддерживающий параллельность в gcc, не переносится в Apple's fork Clang от слова совсем. Проблема не решается подключением библиотек.

Comment: @Давид, т.е. не компилируется код с `std::thread`?

Comment: По-моему, с std::thread как раз все нормально должно быть, еще не пробовал, отпишусь…

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, что влезаю в дискуссию, но может быть вы добавите в вопрос конкретный образец кода, который компилирует GCC, но отвергает apple-clang?

Comment: Любой код, использующий паралллельные версии стандартных (STL) алгоритмов GCC (libstdc++), для которых первым аргументом принимается execution policy.

Answer (score 0):

Да, clang и его стандартная библиотека libc++ поддерживает параллельность. Clang имеет встроенную поддержку для OpenMP и может выполнять параллельные вычисления с помощью директив и функций OpenMP.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "поддерживает параллельность"? Параллельных алгоритмов нет (похоже [только начали делать](https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/PSTL.html)).