# Какие виды параллельности поддерживает libc++?

Tags: c++, распараллеливание

libstdc++ STL в C++17 имеет параллельные версии алгоритмов с execution policy, основанные на tbb. А до этого также имелись параллельные версии основанные на openMP.

А что может предложить в этом плане libc++? Почему тут ничего нет, кроме posix потоков?

Comment: Чем это отличается от [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1518344/215103)? И от [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1518296/215103)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, наверное ТС считает, что чем больше одинаковых вопросов он задаст, тем выше вероятность получить ответ.

Comment: Предыдущий вопрос думал не опубликовался, не смог найти его, либо задержка была. А первый вопрос на который вы ссылку оставили, совсем о другом, вы его для кучи что ли сюда приплели?

Comment: Список ваших вопросов [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/527954/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4). *"совсем о другом"* Ну-ну. Я бы все в один большой вопрос объединил.

Comment: Я так и не понял, чем не угодил TBB. Там все те же самые параллельные алгоритмы, только синтаксис чуть другой.

Comment: HolyBlackCat, проблема в непереносимости кода - если вы использовали параллельные версии алгоритмов STL в libstdc++, то как вы их перенесете в libc++. Тривиальный пример - на работе у вас Linux и gcc, а дома macOS и Xcode с clang’ом (подключить к нему libstdc++ не получится) - и это будут две совершенно разные версии кода. Одна использует STL-алгоритмы, вторая tbb фреймворк. И кстати,  вы скорее всего не сможете tbb к libc++ прикрутить в macOS.

Comment: 1. Пожалуйста пишите `@` перед ником, иначе нам не приходят уведомления. 2. Ну так используйте везде TBB (забейте на параллельные алгоритмы стандартной библиотеки). 3. Никто не предлагает прикрутить "к libc++" (вы имеете в виду сделать так, чтобы в libc++ появились параллельные алгоритмы на основе TBB?). Просто используйте TBB напрямую.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Сейчас есть много технологий для параллельных вычислений - MPI, OpenMP, OpenCL, Cilk Plus, onetbb(tbb), ArBB(Ct), и др. Все это немногим сложнее одно другого. Можно написать свою на худой конец, ибо в основе всех библиотек — нативный интерфейс работы с потоками ОС. Все библиотеки взаимозаменяемы. Но для замены могут потребоваться значительные изменения кода и время на изучение, имплементаци. При проектировании с нуля, об этом можно рассуждать. Но Вас не смущает, что в одной библиотеке это есть нативно (почти), а в другой нет от слова совсем?

Comment: *"Но Вас не смущает"* Не смущает. Это же опенсорс - могли просто не успеть сделать. Или возможно брезгуют TBB и хотят либо написать с нуля, либо никак - надо искать обсуждения. В любом случае вам придется выбирать между альтернативами, потому что писать это самому - сложно и несерьезно. В пользу TBB говорит то, что его выбрали два вендора стандартной библиотеки.